# PlotCandle function in pine script not working when i keep overlay value true

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

PlotCandle function in pine script not working when i keep overlay value true, here  i have small code where i just want to plot candle if a candle body is 50% or less then 50% of its total range of the candle.

If i keep overlay off it works fine but as i change overlay value to true then plotcandle doesn't plot or it take effect until I open and close the settings menu of the indicator,
barcolor()  and plot shape works fine  only plotcandle is not taking effect untill i open & Close indicator setting ,please find code below

```
//@version=5   
indicator("BoringCandle",overlay = true)   boringCandleSize= input.float(defval = 0.5,title = "Candle Size")   
candleBody=math.abs(open-close)   
candleRange=math.abs(high-low)   
isBoring=(candleBody/candleRange) <= boringCandleSize 
candleColor = isBoring ? color.rgb(0,0,255,0):(open < close ? color.green : color.red ) 
plotcandle(open, high, low, close, color = candleColor) 
plotshape(isBoring,color=candleColor)
```

PlotCandle function in pine script not working when i keep overlay value true

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the colour of the candles when the condition is satisfied, use the following function:

> barcolor(isBoring ? color.rgb(0,0,255,0) : na)